# How to view external ip on a google cloud platform compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am logged into a compute engine via ssh.  I am using my personal ssh keys to ssh in.  ie. I did `gcloud compute ssh --project someproj --zone somezone someserver`   to login.  Then I tried to do `gcloud compute instances list` to view the external ip.  It says I have insufficient privileges.  My understanding is that although I have ssh login as my self, I am actually using the service account.  So I edited the service account to have `Role: Compute Viewer` but I still get an error.  What am I doing wrong?

**Please be advised** I know I can view the external IP from console or via my pc using the cli.  I'm more interested in why the compute instance can not see it given the IAM settings.

Here is the actual error:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Here is my gcloud sdk config:

```
$ gcloud config list
[core]
account = some-service-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = some-project

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Compute Engine instance, you have the opportunity to specify "scopes".  Scopes are an older technology where we can constrain requests based on allowed execution scopes.  The default is to "Allow default access" which allows some GCP services and not others.  The other two options are "Allow Full Access" and "Set Access for each API".  If you specify "Allow Full Access" then access to GCP services is exclusively IAM control.  If it is either default or access for each API then you will be governed by BOTH scopes and IAM permissions.

It is likely that you are using default access which prevents the gcloud command you want to run.  Either set "Allow Full Access" or change the specific scope to allow "Compute" scopes.

Comment: You are correct Sir!  I'm using "default access" and "Compute Instance" is "disabled".  i'm guessing "gcloud services enable compute.api.google.com " or whatever is named is disabled as well.  I'll look into it.  I appreciate your quick and accurate respose.

Comment: To add upon this answer which is indeed correct, it is actually Google's recommended practice to set the full cloud-platform access scope on the instance, then securely limit the service account's access using IAM roles as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#service_account_permissions).